# Keyup event or input mask solution for having decimals in text input, but not modify it's decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keyup, jquery-inputmask

I have been trying a lot of solutions for this to work, but basically what I need is to have an input in which you can insert integers, but not decimals, but also show the decimal part as ",00" always. I have been trying with jquery-inputmask with no luck, also have been playing around with events but simply there is too much cases to cover with event.which, would take a long time and at the end could be a risky solution with 2 or 3 bugs because of copy and pasting a number, going forward and backwards with the arrow keys. Neither to say with the cursor, to have it always at the end of the numbers and not be able to alter the decimals.

My jquery solution was something like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(event){
    //In here I check for the user not to insert any period or comma's, as it will always be an integer at the end, also no spaces or letters
    if (event.which == 32 || !(event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) && !(event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105))
        return false;
    //In here I say if the text already have a comma, then check if the value is larger than zero, then add ",00" and set the cursor to the end of the integer part
    if(!(this.value.indexOf(',') != -1)){
        if(accounting.unformat(this.value, ',') >= 0){
            this.value = this.value + ',00';
            this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length - 3, this.value.length - 3);
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see it already takes lots of conditions for it to get exactly the correct user experience, SO, I tried and used jquery-inputmask, and say something like:

```
$('input').inputmask('currency', {
        prefix: '',
        radixPoint: ',',
        allowPlus: false,
        allowMinus: false,
        showMaskOnHover: false,
        showMaskOnFocus: false,
        clearMaskOnLostFocus: true,
        rightAlign: false,
        clearMaskOnLostFocus: true
    });
```

This is a very nice solution, although it still let me change the decimals. I then tried another one, which was to treat it as a decimal instead of currency, and then remove the decimals, and add a suffix as '0,00' to it, like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').inputmask('decimal', {
    prefix: '',
    suffix: ',00', // Adding digits here...
    radixPoint: ',',
    allowPlus: false,
    allowMinus: false,
    showMaskOnHover: false,
    showMaskOnFocus: false,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: true,
    rightAlign: false,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: true,
    digits: 0 // removing digits here...
});
```

This works sort of ok, but as soon as I try to type for an european number such as: 1.234,00, it doesn't let to type in the text box such number. Even worse, if I try to input a comma "," it just starts going crazy and creating a lot of numbers with commas.

I'm using this plugin:
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Anyone had this scenario before?

Thanks!